# Database - Create sequence on a composite key value

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash, sequence

This is a database design scenario where there are several tables with the schema:

```
TABLEx (Id varchar(20), BackupTime datetimeoffset, Name varchar(50), Modstamp datetimeoffset)
```

An application is built around the database schema that (Id, BackupTime) is a composite key. Everytime a data is retrieved at a point in time with the values

```
Id, Name, Modstamp
1, TestAccount, 2018-09-17T19:54:55.000Z
2, TestAccount1, 2018-09-17T19:54:55.000Z
3, DummyAccount2, 2018-09-17T20:58:51.000Z
```

is inserted with the BackupTime value as the current time. The assumption was the Ids are unique when retrieved.

This was proven to be false when I've encountered a scenario for a particular data source where the data looks like this:

```
Id, Name, ReferenceValue, Modstamp
1, Problem1, Reference1, 2018-09-17T19:54:55.000Z
1, Problem2, Reference1, 2018-09-17T19:54:55.000Z
1, Problem1, Reference2, 2018-09-17T20:58:51.000Z
```

and by the looks of it, the data is based on the composite key of [Name, ReferenceValue]. I'd not prefer to change the application because of this particular aberrant. The data is based on the Id and the BackupTime fields for other operations. I wanted to generate a sequence based on the composite key [Name, ReferenceValue]. Is there a way to generate an auto-sequence of varchar(20) for this particular scenario? This would be a way to generate a hash that fits the varchar(20).

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will work for your scenario, but when I have had to do this in the past to get a unique key for a combination of other columns I have done this:

1) Create a table to contain the unique combinations:

```
create table UniqueNameRef(UNameRef int identity not null primary key, Name varchar(20), Ref vrchar(20))
```

2) Insert into this table any new unique combinations, in this example the data is

```
insert UniqueNameRef(Name,Ref) 
select distinct Name, ReferenceValue 
from TABLEx 
where not exists(select * from UniqueNameRef where UniqueNameRef.Name=TABLEx.Name and UniqueNameRef.Ref=TABLEx.ReferenceValue)
```

3) Lookup from this table to get a unique UNameRef for the combination.

```
select Name, ReferenceValue, UNameRef 
from TABLEx
join UniqueNameRef on UniqueNameRef.Name=TABLEx.Name and UniqueNameRef.Ref=TABLEx.ReferenceValue
```

Comment: I thought that was the idea @dmachop - to get a unique key based on Name and ref. Appologies if not - the question is not that clear. Sample expected data would help. BTW dont know what that link in your comment is supposed to show - it doesnt seem to know what an identity key is from the errors.

Comment: I was trying to generate sample data. SQLFiddle was down and thus wasn't able to generate the live data. Here's the sample http://rextester.com/JZRZ81262

This script just generates the incorrect sequence when duplicate value of ('name2', 'ref1') is inserted. Expected to be the same Id and should fail while insert because of the primary key constraint.

Comment: Step 2 of my answer only inserts where the key does not already exist, thus avoiding any chance of inserting a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

In fact SQL Server dont have composite sequence generator, I had 2 ideas work around:

1. Inside Stored Procedure, call dinamically one of many Sequences acordin your composite key
2. Use of MySQL to do this work, with one table MyISAM (version 5.7 supports), this way you can create one table AS generator key, with composite key with one field AUTO_INCREMENT, WHEN you inserts one record of your composite root, you can call SELECT LAST from the same transaction and take your value to that composite key. SO is possible to do
   1-2-1 (generated 1 to composite 1-2)
   1-2-2 (generated 2 to composite 1-2)
   1-1-1 (generated 1 to composite 1-1)
   1-5-1 (generated 1 to composite 1-5)
   1-2-3 (generated 3 to composite 1-2)
   ...